# SE Aviation has a Chat Room - Come join us!

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

Actually, we've had chat ever since this site started, but we're curious how many people are unaware it exists because it's not prominently linked to.

Our main chat room is called [The Hangar](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar). It [requires 20 reputation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) to talk in chat, but unlike the Q&A site where discussion is discouraged, random conversations (especially those related to aviation) are perfectly on-topic.

Have questions about how chat works? Check out its [FAQ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq) first. If that doesn't help, then you can ask in chat itself, or here on meta.

---

This post actually came out of a discussion in chat about how there may be members who are unware chat exists, or unsure how to get there. See the [transcript starting here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22390054#22390054).

As always, if you have ideas for getting more members of the community involved in chat, the blog, or Stack Exchange in general, feel free to propose them. We're doing great as a site and community, but we're always happy to get more people involved.

Comment: while I agree with the message and the idea, I have to ask: what's the question here?  (see comments [here](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1669) )

Comment: And eventually what the OP had to do [there.](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1669)

Comment: @Federico There is no question, read the transcript for the explanation.

Comment: @anshabhi - And I don't think you needed to delete that other question, personally.  You marked it as discussion, there didn't really have to be a question at all.  This is Meta, not the actual stack.

Comment: @JayCarr I have read it. Also, I disagree, we have the `unclear what you're asking` close reason also here.

Comment: @Federico Just because a feature has been ported from one stack to another doesn't meant it needs to be used in the same way, or even be used at all.  You're assuming that just because it exists in the meta area it must be used as it is on a regular stack.  I disagree.  Meta needs discussion, and sometimes that means saying something even when you aren't sure what the question is, or even if there isn't a question to begin with.

Comment: To me a discussion needs a topic. "How to bring people to chat" can be a topic, "hey people we have a chat" I seriously do not see what is to be discussed.

Comment: @Federico - Well, in this case it's just an announcement so we could post it in the sidebar of the Aviation.SE site (seriously, did you read the whole log?)  In other cases it really would depend on the original topic being presented.  I don't know about you, but I've had a lot of discussions that didn't actually start with someone asking a question.  Perhaps that is why we differ.